# In Net Maui can you have conditional compile based on device type?

Tags: c#, maui

I am creating a .Net MAUI app for all device types mobile, tablet, and desktop. Some screens in my app are standard across all device types.

In my app, some pages are specific to a device type and some pages are common across all devices. Obviously, because you have more screen real estate on tablets and desktops.

I also want to have reduced functionality (different page layouts and functions) on mobile devices.

Now I know you can use Device.Idiom to work out the device type (in code) and I'm using that to handle page navigation

```
        if (DeviceInfo.Current.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Phone)
        {
            ... //navigate to a mobile page
        }
        else if (DeviceInfo.Current.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet || DeviceInfo.Current.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Desktop)
        {
            .... //navigate to a tablet/desktop page
        }
```

And that's great, but it dawns on me that unless you can tell the compiler otherwise then all screens will build into all apps, regardless if the app uses that screen or not. You can imagine on a mobile device then, will be carrying a payload that it will never ever use.

Obviously, on Android and iOS, I would love to be able to conditional compile if it's a tablet or a phone. I can only see options to distinguish between platform types.

I don't really want to write two apps and share code. I could do that but I'd rather just maintain one project if I can.

Check this article [MAUi multitargeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting) where you can set up your project for different platforms. There doesn't seem to be a way I can find to segregate based on device type, phone, tablet, computer etc.

Is there a compiler directive `#if ...` that I can use to distinguish between mobile and tablet so only the mobile screens are compiled into that app?

Comment: The actual difference in size of adding a few additional pages should be very negligible.  And  doing what you’re suggesting would require separate builds for each device type in the App stores

Comment: MAUI's conditional compilation is only set up for different platforms, not for device types. I'm sure there is a (complicated) way to achieve what you're trying to do using additional compiler constants and conditions, but then you would also need to deliver different APKs and IPAs to the app stores for the different device types.

Comment: @Jason, thanks for that I totally get that, just seems a bit wrong as my tablet version will have about 50% more functionality and pages than the mobile version. Essentially the mobile version provides a "quick hit/access" if you only need a short flyby whereas the tablet version allows you to "sit down" and do everything.

Comment: @ewerspej I kind of suspected that but I wanted to check.

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described.

Comment: This isn't a code problem, my code is fine, what I want to know is as the question states, can you conditional compile based on device type, not just on platform type?

Comment: If so, you can build for each device individually as Jason said.